# How can I replace delay() by millis()?

Tags: c, arduino, ide, delay

After a while, I get my final result I want but I can't use delay because I need different time for different strip, so I need to replace `delay()` by `millis()` in this code:

```
#include <FastLED.h>
#define NUM_LEDS1 10
#define NUM_LEDS2 6
#define DATA_PIN1 6
#define DATA_PIN2 7
CRGB leds1[NUM_LEDS1];
CRGB leds2[NUM_LEDS2];

void setup() { 
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN1>(leds1, NUM_LEDS1);
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN2>(leds2, NUM_LEDS2);
}

int dot_delay1[ ] = { 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000 };
int dot_delay2[ ] = { 100,200,300,400,500,600 };

void loop() {
  for(int dot = 0; dot < NUM_LEDS1; dot++)
    for(int dot = 0; dot < NUM_LEDS2; dot++) 
    { 
      leds1[dot] = CRGB::Blue;
      leds2[dot] = CRGB::Blue;
      FastLED.show();
      leds1[dot] = CRGB::Black;
      leds2[dot] = CRGB::Black;
      delay( dot_delay1[ dot ] );
      // this is where I need to put the second delay,
      // but I can't put more then 1 delay.
      // I need to refactor my code with millis() function instead of delay()
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify the used language in the tags.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks is my first post here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-blocking code patterns, which are executed in special frequencies or times. In the following, I give you an short example how you can replace a `delay(1000)` and a `delay(5000)` without blocking the main loop. In addition, you can check stackoverflow for similar posts (e.g. [Pause without Delay() arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792093/pause-without-delay-arduino/31801686#31801686)).

```c
// 1 sec. frequency
unsigned long interval=1000;    // the time we need to wait
unsigned long previousMillis=0; // millis() returns an unsigned long.

// 5 sec. frequency  
unsigned long interval1=5000;    // the time we need to wait
unsigned long previousMillis1=0; // millis() returns an unsigned long.

void setup() {
   //...
}

void loop() {

 // other CMD's...

 // replace delay(1000) 
 if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis) >= interval) {
    previousMillis = millis();
    // every first second
    // ... 
 }

 // other CMD's...

 // replace delay(5000) 
 if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis1) >= interval1) {
    previousMillis1 = millis();
    // every fifth second
    // ... 
 }

 // other CMD's...
}
```

Comment: like you see in my first code example i have a `int dot_delay1[ ] = { 100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000 };` is for 10 delay for the same strip ( and the strip have 10 pixel so 10 delay value) anyway clue how to do this for millis()? how to make a multiple `millis(100,200,300)` like my example?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using NeoPixels! It just so happens that Adafruit has some great tutorials on using `millis()` and `micros()` for timing purposes instead of `delay()`. They also include good material on interrupts, if you're feeling ambitious and want to separate your timing from your main function entirely (a worthwhile undertaking, if you have the time and resources).

Part 1 (basics of using `millis()`):

https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/overview

Part 2 (introduces interrupts):

https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-2/overview

Part 3 (puts everything together):

https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-3/overview

---

### Edit 1:

Alright, I edited your code, adding in a loop that checks for both delay periods to be done using `millis()`. I attempted to stick to the variable naming conventions that you've been using, for easy readability. There were also some other issues with your code syntax that I cleaned up. Make sure to effectively comment your code so that it's understandable, for yourself and for others!

Hopefully this works the way you want it to!

```
/*The goal of the sketch is to run multiple strip where each dot could be 
controlled on/off one after the others but with different times on/off between each
pixel on each strip. All be independent and separate and automated and structured
already like FastLED library recommendation.*/

// Library include
#include <FastLED.h>

#define NUM_LEDS1 10
#define NUM_LEDS2 6

// Define pin (each strip be connected on)
#define DATA_PIN1 5
#define DATA_PIN2 6

// Declare some strip name and attribute (number of led per strip)
CRGB leds1[NUM_LEDS1];
CRGB leds2[NUM_LEDS2];

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN1>(leds1, NUM_LEDS1);
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, DATA_PIN2>(leds2, NUM_LEDS2);
}

int dot_delay1[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000};
int dot_delay2[] = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600};

void loop() {
  for (int dot1 = 0; dot1 < NUM_LEDS1; dot1++) {
    for (int dot2 = 0; dot2 < NUM_LEDS2; dot2++) {
      // LED turns blue
      leds1[dot1] = CRGB::Blue;
      leds2[dot2] = CRGB::Blue;
      // Show LED status
      FastLED.show();
      // LED turns black
      leds1[dot1] = CRGB::Black;
      leds2[dot2] = CRGB::Black;
      // Create timing variables
      unsigned long previousMillis = millis();
      unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
      // Create boolean variables to monitor if the delays have triggered yet
      bool delayFlag1 = false, delayFlag2 = false;
      // Loop continuously
      while (1) {
        currentMillis = millis();
        // If the first delay time has passed, delayFlag1 is true
        if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis) >= dot_delay1[dot1]) {
          delayFlag1 = true;
        }
        // If the second delay time has passed, delayFlag2 is true
        if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis) >= dot_delay2[dot2]) {
          delayFlag2 = true;
        }
        // If both delay times have passed (both delay flags are true), exit while loop
        if ((delayFlag1 && delayFlag2) == true) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This new code should work, I've tested it and it works as expected on my machine.

As a side note, your original question was "How can I replace delay() by millis()?". This question has been answered both by myself and by the previous answer author, user3704293. In the future it may be helpful to separate your questions to get higher quality answers and to better serve those who are searching for answers to the same questions. Once your question is answered, as I hope this question is now, you should accept the answer that is the best for you.

Let me know if it all works out!

---

### Edit 2:

To have LEDs change independently of each other, replace the `loop()` function in the previous code with this one.

```
void loop() {
  // Create timing variable
  unsigned long previousMillis = millis();
  // Loop through all LEDs
  for (int dot = 0; dot < NUM_LEDS1; dot++) {
    // If the first delay time has passed, change first LED strip
    if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis) >= dot_delay1[dot1]) {
      leds1[dot - 1] = CRGB::Black;
      leds1[dot] = CRGB::Blue;
    }
    // If the second delay time has passed, change second LED strip
    if ((unsigned long)(millis() - previousMillis) >= dot_delay2[dot2]) {
      leds2[dot - 1] = CRGB::Black;
      leds2[dot] = CRGB::Blue;
    }
    // Show LEDs
    FastLED.show();
  }
  // Turn last LED Black
  leds1[9] = CRGB::Black;
}
```

Comment: Yes is like 2 weeks now i check all this tutorial...but feel lost cause iam not native coder and i try to fix my code allready uphere.

Comment: @FrançoisEricKing I'll edit my post and attempt to figure out a solution to your promises, give me a little while. I haven't personally used NeoPixels, so I'll do my best, but no promises! It would also help if you clarified exactly what the "second delay" would be used for.

Comment: The second delay is the serie of delay for the.second strip led :)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, let me know if the code I posted works for you.

Comment: i test it wow thanks  but is not work. First pixel of each strip going to blue but nothing more. here is a pastebin of you code and i put more detail in comment inside the file... maybe that help to understand. http://pastebin.com/d9SW62du

Comment: The answer is edited and should work for you now. Please consider my written comments at the end of the answer.

Comment: thanks for reply. I tested the new corrected code and is not work like expected. delay/milles 1 is look ''linked'' to delay/millis 2 array...both array delay need to be completely indepandant and without any interaction on each other. Is look like if i change value in dot_delay1, dot_delay2 (or strip2) have changing delay too. I try to figure out what is linked and fork something for completely indepandant control on each strip...not i relation or linked :) Thanks

Comment: Sorry it's not working the way you wanted. If this answer is sufficient for your original question, please accept it. I also posted some code that makes the LEDs behave how you want them to. I added this in a new edit because the original code may be useful for someone searching for the answer to your original question. The best thing to do in the future is ask individual questions about each question / problem you have. As you can see, I've answered a number of your questions here :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!